# Magento 1.8.1 SUPEE-8788 "saving rejects to file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php.rej"

Tags: patches, ce-1.8.1.0, supee-8788

I am scratching my hair on this. Here is what I did to apply the `SUPEE-8788 patch` to my 1.8.1 store:

- Never installed Revert SUPEE-8788 v1
- Reverted SUPEE-1533 successfully
- Never installed SUPEE-3941
- Trying to Install SUPEE-8788 v2, and here is the only error I get:

> patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
>       patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
>       patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
>       patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
>       Hunk #1 FAILED at 372.
>       1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file     downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php.rej
>       patching file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
>       patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
>       patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js

I found a suggestion to replace the Curl.php file with original 1.8.1 download - I did this as well, but I still get the error.

Please help!

Comment: did you installed 3941?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got this issue :

```
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php Hunk #1 FAILED at 372.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php.rej
```

That means you don't have install the previous patch SUPEE-3941

Installing this patch is mandatory before applying the SUPEE-8788's patch.

Comment: Perfect. Installing SUPEE-3941 solved the problem. Thank you Kozame.